# How to display an "Open File" popup withoug using Win32 API

Tags: c++, file, user-interface

I'm working on the editor for my game engine. At the moment, to load in a project, you have to type in the full path of the project file, which is annoying, and slow. How can I display a file popup box to select a file and then return it's path as a string? I am using Windows, but I would prefer not to use the Win32 API, for cross-platform purposes. My project uses Dear ImGui, so is there a way to harness that to display a list of files that can be selected? What I need to know how to do is to grab a list of drives, files and folders, and somehow store them in a tree (maybe something similar to an `std::vector` of `std::maps`?) which I can use with ImGui to create a popup where you can select files from different drives and folders.

Comment: Even if you don't directly use Windows API functions in your code, they must still be used *somewhere* for at least iterating the directory structure. So either submit to that fact, and implement it yourself, or if your compiler and standard library is new enough to support [the C++17 standard filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) you could use [`directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) to iterate over a directory (but note that it will likely use Windows API functions).

Comment: And unless the user-interface library you use in your engine support dialogs similar to "open file" dialogs, you need to design and implement it yourself.

Comment: https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/wiki#file-browsers

Comment: Yes, you could do that. Or you could use windows's open file popup

Comment: @user253751 I want to avoid using the Windows one, because it isn't cross platform. I mainly use GNU/Linux, so I want to be able to build on that as well.